# How to make only one part of a div row scrollable (using clarity instead of bootstrap styling)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a angular project with dot net core, and i'm struggling with some styling in one component.

I have a row which contains 2 columns, the first column is empty and the second column contains another row with multiple columns filled with random numbers, i only want to make the second column that contains the row with multiple columns horizontally scrollable. The first column that which is empty should not be scrollable.

(I just added random numbers to the columns to fill it with some content.)

I've tried the `white-space: nowrap` in the styling with the `overflow-x: auto` and set to scroll, but the columns that should be scrollable are not scrolling instead its stacking on-top of each other.

```html
<div class="clr-row ">
  <div class="clr-col-2" style="background-color:aqua">
    <span >.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clr-col-10" style="overflow-x:auto; width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:rebeccapurple">
        <span>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:brown;">
        <span>2 2 2 2 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:burlywood;">
        <span>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:cadetblue;">
        <span>4 4 4 4 4 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:deeppink;">
        <span> 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:greenyellow;">
        <span>6 6 6 6 6 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:orange;">
        <span>7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:black;">
        <span>8 8 8 8 8 8 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:dimgrey;">
        <span>9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:palegoldenrod;">
        <span>0 0 0 0 0 0 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:lightcoral;">
        <span>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:wheat;">
        <span>2 2 2 2 2 2 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:teal;">
        <span>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:Highlight;">
        <span>4 4 4 4 4 4 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I only want the second columns which consist of a row with many columns inside with the random numbers to be scrollable and the first one should be static.

Screenshot of the output I'm currently getting where the second column that contains the row with the many columns are stacking on-top of each other instead of giving the option to scroll.
[image: Output]

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit better? Because what do you want with your second row?

Comment: @ xmastertje --- i edited my question a bit to explain it more.

Comment: @A.vdWalt If you click *Run* on your snippet there is a different output then your image is showing. Did you add all your code?

Comment: @MiXT4PE--yes added it as is in the component, i think it looks different because i'm using clarity and not bootstrap, so i'm not sure if it picks up that i'm using clarity instead of bootstrap when you run the snippet.

Comment: Could you provide a link to *Clarity* I'm interested in what this is but I've had no luck googling

Comment: @MIXT4PE-- https://v1.clarity.design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.
I warped the second column which contains the row with the many columns with a div tag and added styling to make that div tag scrollable and then inside the new div tag i used to wrap the column i added another div tag to expand the width of that column larger than its set value, this resolved the issues where my columns where stacked on-top of each other

```html
<div class="clr-row ">
  <div class="clr-col-2" style="background-color:aqua">
    <span>.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clr-col-10">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;white-space:nowrap">
      <div style="width:1920px">
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:lavender;float:left">
            <span>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:brown;float:left">
            <span>2 2 2 2 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:burlywood;float:left">
            <span>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:cadetblue;float:left">
            <span>4 4 4 4 4 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:deeppink;float:left">
            <span> 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:greenyellow;float:left">
            <span>6 6 6 6 6 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:orange;float:left">
            <span>7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:black;float:left">
            <span>8 8 8 8 8 8 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:dimgrey;float:left">
            <span>9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:palegoldenrod;float:left">
            <span>0 0 0 0 0 0 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:lightcoral;float:left">
            <span>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:wheat;float:left">
            <span>2 2 2 2 2 2 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:teal;float:left">
            <span>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:Highlight;float:left">
            <span>4 4 4 4 4 4 </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please do keep in mind i'm using clarity and not bootstrap that is why when you run the snippet it looks different than the screen shot.

Screenshot of my output.
[image: Final_Output]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem but you can use `position: fixed` to fix the first row.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="clr-row ">
  <div class="clr-col-2" style="background-color:aqua; position:fixed; width:100%; top:0;">
    <span>.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clr-col-10" style="overflow-x:auto; width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:rebeccapurple">
        <span>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:brown;">
        <span>2 2 2 2 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:burlywood;">
        <span>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:cadetblue;">
        <span>4 4 4 4 4 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:deeppink;">
        <span> 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:greenyellow;">
        <span>6 6 6 6 6 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:orange;">
        <span>7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:black;">
        <span>8 8 8 8 8 8 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:dimgrey;">
        <span>9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:palegoldenrod;">
        <span>0 0 0 0 0 0 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:lightcoral;">
        <span>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:wheat;">
        <span>2 2 2 2 2 2 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:teal;">
        <span>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col" style="background-color:Highlight;">
        <span>4 4 4 4 4 4 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MiXT4PE-- i edited my question to explain it a bit more.

Comment: @MiXT4PE-- it only moves the first column to the top of the page leaving the column that contains the row with many columns at the bottom, and it is still not scrolling it is stacking the columns instead of giving an option to scroll.

Comment: @MiXT4PE-- i added a image to explain what i'm currently getting.